# Pegar o diretório do executável e salvar imagem em uma pasta dentro deste diretório

Tags: c#

Eu precisava pegar o caminho do executável e salvar em uma pasta dentro do diretório raiz onde está o ".exe", servindo tanto na programação do arquivo na pasta "bin" e "debug" quanto na hora de criar o instalador com o "inno setup" e abrir em qualquer pasta designada pelo usuário na hora de instalar o arquivo. Está pegando o nome do arquivo e salvando no formato "bmp" mas não está funcionando a parte de pegar e salvar a pasta no diretório do executável vejam o meu código abaixo;

```
 string pastaimagem = "imagem";
 string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
 Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(bmp, pictureBox2.Size);
            pictureBox2.Image = bmp2;
            string pasta = appPath + pastaimagem;
            if (!Directory.Exists(pasta))
            {


                Directory.CreateDirectory(pasta);

            }          

            pictureBox2.Image.Save(pasta + txtCod.Text + ".bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar o caminho do diretório tanto no debug ou quando o programa já estiver rodando em algum PC use o comando a seguir:

```
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory

Ex: txtCaminhoRaiz.Text = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
```